# CompletionSuggester stops working when adding custom analyzer. NEST C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We're using ElasticSearch on AWS and using NEST to create the index.

When accessing our server URLs _mapping I can see the completionsuggester like this:

```
"matchSuggest": {
"type": "completion",
"analyzer": "simple",
"payloads": true,
"preserve_separators": true,
"preserve_position_increments": true,
"max_input_length": 50
}
```

MatchIndex is declared like this:

```
 public class MatchIndex
 {
        ...
        public CompletionField<object> MatchSuggest { get; set; }
 }
```

But then we try to add a custom analyzer to our index for another class and it breaks all the completion suggesters.

```
client.CreateIndex("search", i => i
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfShards(5)
        .NumberOfReplicas(1)
        .Analysis(analysis => analysis
        .TokenFilters(tokenfilters => tokenfilters
            .AsciiFolding("folding-preserve", ft => ft
                .PreserveOriginal()
            )
        )

.Mappings(m => m
    .Map<PlayerIndex>(map => map
        .AutoMap().Properties(ps => ps
         .String( s => s
            .Name(n => n.Name)
            .Fields(f => f
                .String(ss => ss
                    .Name("folding")
                    .Analyzer("folding-analyzer")
                    )
             )
             .NotAnalyzed()
         )
        .Completion(c => c
            .Name(p => p.SquadMemberSuggest)
            .Payloads()
        )

        )       

    )
```

When I now access the _mapping endpoint all the suggesters are not listed as completion suggesters anymore. No errors given. This seems to happen everytime we try to add a custom analyzer. Is there any reason for this? Does Elasticsearch have any error logs we can look at to find the reason for things like this happening?

```
"matchSuggest": {
    "properties": {
      "input": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "output": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "payload": {
        "properties": {
          "awayTeamId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "homeTeamId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "weight": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  },
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "parentLeagueId": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "statusId": {
    "type": "long"
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you have two types in one index and are setting up completion fields on both types on the same field name with different analyzers?

Comment: @RussCam Actually we have 4 types in one index. Each has it's own completion field (unique name) but yes some share the "name" property so yes that's the bug! We can't have a different analyzer when they share the same property name in the same index. Can you write that as an answer so I can mark it? :)

Comment: Sure, you knew the answer I was going to write :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion type field uses an FST (Finite State Transducer) data structure to provide autocompletion. A single FST is created *per field per index*, so having two types in the same index with the same field set up as a `completion` field will mean that the field mapping settings for both fields would need to be the same. In fact, fields with the same name on different types in the same index also have this limitation.

You may consider solving this by using different field names on the types for the completion field or having only one type per index.